# Touchscreen worked on "try without install" and now does not

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen, ideapad

So recently, I bought a Lenovo Ideapad z400, which has a wonderful 10-point multi-touch screen. I absolutely hate Windows 8, so I decided to try to dual boot Ubuntu. I did the installation after the trial worked **perfectly** with the touchscreen. But ever since, the touch screen is not recognized by Ubuntu-or so it seems. (It still works on windows 8.)
 I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, as this is my first time ever using any Linux OS, as well as a touchscreen laptop. Anyone able to help or have any thoughts on this?

Comment: It says "there are no proprietary drivers in use" and doesn't list anything.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Someone else may have a solution. See this bug report and if it matches your situation: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1099289

Comment: It's similar, but not exact. I can't get the touchscreen to work at all, where they seem to have it working for some time, then stopping. But someone else with a z400 seems to have that bug, so I'll look into it a bit more.

Comment: Also- Just this morning, after lettiing it 'suspend'/sleep overnight on ubuntu, rather than shutting it down, I signed in, and now the touchscreen is just fine. Weird...

Comment: This may be the work around for you, until a fix is released. I read for some people, suspend and resume brings the touch screen back into action. I don't remember where I saw it though. All the best.