# Touchscreen worked during install and now does not

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, xubuntu, touchscreen

During the install, or the "try ubuntu" the touch screen works perfectly fine.  But once the install is done, then the touchscreen doesn't work at all.
I've tried ubutnu Desktop 14LTS and 16LTS also tried gnome ubuntu 16.

hardware: Lenovo thinpad X201

I've seen [this posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320379/touchscreen-worked-on-try-without-install-and-now-does-not), but there was never a solution

**UPDATE (can't make comments yet)**
Yes I connected to the internet to allow updates, and install 3rd party packages.
I've also installed linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic.

**UPDATE** here is lsusb output

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c6:9204 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 17ef:4816 Lenovo Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Did you check the options to install third party software and download updates while installing?